# React: How to pass the data from function located on the child component into parent component?

Tags: reactjs

I have a function called handleDelete that contains the id of specific task. I want to pass the value of that function to my parent component because this will be my reference for my prompt component. The prompt component contains the title of the task that's the reason that I want to get the task id.

**Parent Component**

```
const Home = ({ history }) => {
  const [taskDeleteId, setDaskDeleteId] = useState();
  const [showPrompt, setShowPrompt] = useState(false);

  return (
    <>
        <Grid>
          <TasksList deleteId={(deleteId) => setDaskDeleteId(deleteId)} /> 
          <PromptComponent showPrompt={showPrompt} taskId={taskIdref} />
        </Grid>
    </>
  );
};

export default Home;
```

**Child Component**

```
const TasksList = ({ taskId, deleteId }) => {
  //Function
  const handleDelete = (e) => {
    deleteId = e.currentTarget.getAttribute('taskId');
    setAssignTask(assignTask.filter((task) => task._id !== deleteId));
  };

  return (
    <>
      <Container
        component='div'
        maxWidth='xl'
        className={classes.taskContainer}
      >
        <Container
          component='div'
          maxWidth='xl'
          className={classes.todoContainer}
          onDragOver={(e) => onDragOverTask(e)}
          onDragLeave={(e) => onDragLeaveTask(e)}
          onDrop={(e) => onDropTask(e)}
        >
          {taskTodo.map((currentTask, index) => {
            return (
              <Card
                variant='outlined'
                className={classes.cardTask}
                key={index}
                style={{ background: '#f3f3f3', marginTop: '1rem' }}
                onDragStart={(e) => onDragStartTask(e, currentTask._id)}
                draggable
              >
                <div className={classes.topContent}>
                  <CardActions
                    className={
                      classes[
                        currentTask.priority === 'High'
                          ? 'checkBoxContainerHigh'
                          : currentTask.priority === 'Minor'
                          ? 'checkBoxContainerMinor'
                          : currentTask.priority === 'Low'
                          ? 'checkBoxContainerLow'
                          : 'checkBoxContainer'
                      ]
                    }
                  >
                    <Checkbox
                      icon={<CircleUnchecked />}
                      checkedIcon={<CircleCheckedFilled />}
                      color='primary'
                      className={classes.completeAction}
                      id={currentTask._id}
                      checked={currentTask.isComplete}
                      onChange={handleCheckStatus}
                    />
                  </CardActions>
                  <CardContent className={classes.cardContentTop}>
                    <Typography variant='h6'>{currentTask.title}</Typography>
                    <Typography variant='caption' color='textSecondary'>
                      <EventIcon />
                      {moment(currentTask.dateDue).format('dddd, Do MMMM')}
                    </Typography>
                  </CardContent>
                  {currentTask.desc && (
                    <CardActions disableSpacing style={{ marginLeft: 'auto' }}>
                      <IconButton
                        className={clsx(classes.expand, {
                          [classes.expandOpen]: expanded,
                        })}
                        onClick={handleChange(`todo-panel_${index}`)}
                      >
                        <ExpandMoreIcon />
                      </IconButton>
                    </CardActions>
                  )}
                </div>
                {currentTask.desc && (
                  <Collapse
                    in={expanded === `todo-panel_${index}`}
                    timeout='auto'
                    unmountOnExit
                    className={classes.collapsePanel}
                    color='primary'
                  >
                    <CardContent className={classes.descPrevContainer}>
                      <Typography
                        variant='body1'
                        className={classes.text}
                        dangerouslySetInnerHTML={createMarkup(
                          textTruncate(currentTask.desc, 50)
                        )}
                      ></Typography>
                    </CardContent>
                  </Collapse>
                )}
                <CardActions
                  disableSpacing
                  className={classes.bottomActionsContainer}
                >
                  <Tooltip title='Delete'>
                    <IconButton
                      aria-label='delete'
                      className={classes.BottomDelete}
                      taskid={currentTask._id}
                      onClick={handleDelete}
                    >
                      <DeleteIcon />
                    </IconButton>
                  </Tooltip>
                  <Tooltip title='Edit'>
                    <IconButton
                      aria-label='edit'
                      className={classes.BottomEdit}
                      taskid={currentTask._id}
                    >
                      <EditIcon />
                    </IconButton>
                  </Tooltip>
                </CardActions>
              </Card>
            );
          })}
        </Container>
      </Container>
    </>
  );
};
```

Comment: With a callback, like any other reverse-direction methods. That said--if you find yourself "needing" to do that a lot it's more likely the state needs to be lifted either up, or out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a previous commenter mentioned, pass a callback down to the Child. Update your parent component as follows

```
const Home = ({ history }) => {
  const [taskDeleteId, setDaskDeleteId] = useState();
  const [showPrompt, setShowPrompt] = useState(false);

  return (
    <>
      <Grid>
        <TasksList deleteId={taskDeleteId} setDeleteId={setDaskDeleteId} />
        <PromptComponent showPrompt={showPrompt} taskId={taskIdref} />
      </Grid>
    </>
  );
};
```

Then in your child you can call the function passed from the parent to set the state properly.

```
const TasksList = ({ taskId, deleteId, setDeleteId }) => {
  // Function
  const handleDelete = (e) => {
    setDeleteId(e.currentTarget.getAttribute('taskId'));
    ...
  };

  return (...
```